# Wireless communication between multiple microcontrollers?

Tags: wireless

I have 3-6 microcontrollers, up to 2m apart. One of them is designated the server and will be fed sensor data from the others, at least at 100 Hz. (Each data point is just a couple of bytes)

Since the microcontrollers move around, I can't connect them with wires. What's a good wireless solution here?

My initial idea was Bluetooth, mainly because that's the one solution I'm familiar with, but Bluetooth consumes much power (my circuits will be battery-powered) and Bluetooth modules are expensive.

Comment: Data at 100Hz, does that mean 100×a couple of bytes / sec?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/53229/17592

Comment: @CamilStaps: Yes, and that the latency must be lower than 1/(100Hz).

Comment: The nRF24L01+ seems to be what I'm looking for. It can both send and receive, right? Can it receive on multiple channels, so that all clients can communicate with the server simultaneously?

Comment: (It seems so with its "6 data pipe MultiCeiver")  What's the range of the nRF24L01+? I can't seem to find that anywhere in the data sheet.

Comment: Is an alternative just to store the data locally for (say) several hours and just upload it at the end of the day with plugs and sockets? Collision detection and retry stuff can get a little complex.

Comment: @Andyaka No, the data will be visualised in real-time.

Comment: The nRF24L01+ has been used in remote photoflash controllers up to 100m so a couple of metres is no problem - there are some ready built modules on ebay for a few dollars ready to connect up to a few I/O lines on you micros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communicating within a couple of meters range, these nRF24L01+ modules, at [around $1.42 apiece on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Arduino-NRF24L01-2-4GHz-Antenna-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-For-Microcontroll-/310670158878?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4855626c1e),  would suit the requirements:

[image: Module]

The module has a PCB trace antenna, which does a pretty reasonable job.

The range seems to be stable at around 6-7 meters during the day, and I have occasionally seen as much as 20-25 meters late at night when most other electronic devices in the vicinity are off.

Sparkfun sells a [similar module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/705) but with an SMA connector for an external antenna, which claims as much as 100 meters range at 250 kbps data rate. Of course, at nearly $20 plus the cost of an antenna, that may be overkill for the required 2 meter range.

Relevant to the specific application:

The key improvement of the nRF24L01+ over the now obsolete nRF24L01 is the implementation of an auto-retransmit feature, which addresses the collision detection complexity concern raised in comments on the question.